# On the integral $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Is there any closed form for the following integral?

$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}} \mathrm{d}x$$

---

Background:

I've been initially trying to compute the following integral

$$I =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt{\sin x \cos x}}\mathrm{d}x.$$

Differentiating the integral function

$$I(t) =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(t\sin x)}{\sqrt{\sin x \cos x}}\mathrm{d}x,$$

leads to

$$I'(t) =\frac{4}{t}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}} \mathrm{d}x,$$

which motivates this question.

Comment: It can be expressed in terms of beta function as $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}B(1/4,1/4)$. This further simplifies to $\Gamma^2(1/4)/2\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: Write it as $$
\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\int_0^{\pi /2} {\sin ^{ - 1/2} x\cos ^{ - 1/2} x\,{\rm d}x}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\int_0^{\pi /2} {\sin ^{2 \cdot 1/4 - 1} x\cos ^{2 \cdot 1/4 - 1} x\,{\rm d}x} 
$$ and use [$(5.12.2)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E2).

Comment: Further I don't see how it helps to evaluate the integral $I(t) $. Your $I(t) $ is $I(1)+\log t\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos x}} \, dx$ and then $I'(t) =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{t}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}}$ so that there is a typo as well.

Comment: It equals the [lemniscate constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lemniscate+constant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin (2x)}}$$
$$x=\frac \pi 4-t \qquad \implies \qquad I=-\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\cos (2 t)}}=-\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2(t)}}$$ Using Elliptic integrals
$$I=-F(t|2)=-F\left(\left.\frac{\pi }{4}-x\right|2\right)$$

$$J=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin (2x)}}=\sqrt{2}\,\, K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi ^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2} \,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$$